# Mongoose cursor with async operations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am new to mongo and now drowned in whole lot of documentation.All I want is to use mongoose cursor to work async with my data operation inside cursor.It should wait to play next iteration until operation is complete.
I read in a that we can do so by

- > QueryCursor#eachAsync(fn, [options], [options.parallel], [callback])
- > If fn returns a promise, will wait for the promise to resolve

Since i am new to mongo I don't know how to create a promise and resolve it later.

```
var cursor = Users.find({ "is_verified" : false }).cursor();
cursor.eachAsync(function (doc) { 
    //create promise here
    async.series({
       one: function(callback){
          callback(null,1);
       },
       two: function(callback){
          callback(null,2);
       },
       three: function(callback){
          callback(null,3);
       },
       four: function(callback){
          //resolve promise here
          if() callback(null,4)
       },
   },function(err,result){})


}).then(()=>console.log('FINISHED'));
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? I wanna help.

Comment: All I want to do is fetch data from my database one-by-one perform operations on them (that will be feeding data in a html template and send a mail to the user) that will be a series of async operations and keep repeating it for all data.

Comment: So the flow would be something like: find(1) -> waitForFindFinish(1) -> storeInVariable(1) -> find(2) -> waitForFindFinish(2) -> storeInVariable(2) ->... -> find(n) -> waitForFindFinish(n) -> storeInVariable(n)   ???

Comment: find(1) -> waitForFindFinish(1) -> feedDetailInTemplate(1) -> sendMailofTemplate(1)  -->  find(2) -> waitForFindFinish(2) -> feedDetailInTemplate(2) -> sendMailofTemplate(2)...............

Comment: So only the parameters of the find are changing?

Comment: yes , and the output from find will be fed in the template so its dependent

Answer (score 0):

I would call your function in an array like this:
[This is semi pseudo-code]

```
for(parameter in parameters) {
  users.find({"parameter":parameter}, function( err, data) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    functionToFeedTemplate(data);
    functionToSendMail(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank for the answer but i did in by taking a way round. By returning a null promise and resolving it in call_back of `async.series([...])`